What can I do to remedy stair risers with gaps at the wall?
We're removing the carpet on our stairs and want to keep the wood stairs pretty basic underneath. However, the risers don’t meet the wall going almost all the way up. How can we fix it?
 

How you want the finish stairs to look would help.  Just paint, you might be able to add small pieces to the end and paint over to hide.  Being able to get under the stairs will help.  Replacing the risers should not be too hard either.

Honestly, it looks like it's just the risers that don't meet the wall.  OP, you could simply face the risers with some thin material (1/4" plywood?), paint the whole shebang, and call it a day.

Option 1:  Lose the cat, and re-carpet the stairs.  I recognize that people for some reason like their cats tho, so...
Option 2:  Refinish the stairs by replacing them with wood that isn't designed to be covered with carpet.

This doesn't really address the question posed in any particular way. The question clearly states that carpet is not desired, and there's no need to completely replace the stairs.

Install thin plywood overlays.
You can purchase a sheet of 1/4" plywood with a nice top layer and rip it to size. You'll want to use a table saw or a clamped straightedge and circular saw for very straight cuts.
Then, simply install it with a combination of double-sided foam tape and construction adhesive (the former for temporary hold, the latter for a permanent bond).
Clean the existing risers to remove any contaminants, and scrape them to remove paint bumps, etc.
